# Why is the R substr function so much slower than slicing in Python?

Tags: python, r, performance, substring, slice

While attempting to optimize a script I was writing, I stumbled across something that has me confused.  In R, if I want to grab 1 character out of a string at a specific location, it seems like the substr function is my best bet.  In python, it makes sense to perform the same operation using slice notation.  What is confusing to me is just how different the speeds of these two operations are.  I wrote two test scripts to showcase this:

**In Python:**

```
import time

test = "testtesttesttesttesttesttest"

startTime = time.time()

result = list()
for i in range(100000):
    result.append(test[19])

stopTime = time.time()

print(stopTime - startTime)
```

**In R:**

```
library(microbenchmark)
test = "testtesttesttesttesttesttest"

testWithSubstr = function() {

  result = character(123456)
  for(i in 1:123456) {
    result[i] = substr(test, 20, 20)
  }

}

print(microbenchmark(testWithSubstr()))
```

(edited to use a for loop instead of sapply for a better comparison and to use microbenchmark)

The Python code runs over 10 times faster, despite (to my knowledge) doing essentially the same thing.  Why is this?

Comment: I guess the bottleneck is at  `sapply`, rather than `substr`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding  I also ran the R script using a for loop and a pre-allocated character vector.  The difference in speed between the R and Python code was still over 10x.  Should I edit the question to make note of this?

Comment: `sapply` is a syntactic sugar of `for´ loop, which doesn't improve the performance too much. loops in R is slower than in python. Perhaps this would be helpful https://datascienceplus.com/loops-in-r-and-python-who-is-faster/

Comment: I don't use R so I can't say for sure, but based off of the parameters of substr it appears that on each iteration it is going to calculate the starting and ending point. All python is doing is looking for the item at the 19th index. R is looking for all items between 20 and 20 which is only 20 and it will iterate through each one. That's assuming I am reading the function correctly.

Comment: I suggest you use `microbenchmark` package to measure average speed in R

Comment: You need to compare your previous result with the vectorized R method: `result2 <-substr(rep(test, 100000),20, 20)`. For me this ran 50x the sapply version.

Comment: I think that @Dave2e's comment is most relevant for this question as it's presented. If you're looking to see how `substr` works on a long input vector, using the vectorized method would make more sense.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you!  That is very helpful.  However, it does not quite answer the question I am asking.  Why is using the vectorized function so much faster?  Why is the method shown above so much slower?

Comment: A very general answer, R scripts is interpreted language, while R’s vectorized functions are complied code. Thus looping to run an interpreted command over and over is much slower than passing a vector once to a machine optimized function.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you very much.  That makes a lot more sense.